# Virtualize XP machines on demand

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, windows-xp

Here's my situation: My company uses an application that only works with XP, needs to be able to access network printers, and exports information in Excel. We need to move off XP before support runs out. We plan to move to Windows 7. I have a mixed Server 2003/2008 environment with our terminal server running 2008.

Here's my question: What's going to be the easiest way to still support this program moving forward? Caveats: The application can't run on Terminal Services or over RDP. I am aware of XP mode in Windows 7, I'd rather not take this route as there seems like a lot of administrative overhead for the amount of users who'd be using this.

Ideally what I'd like is a server a user can hit and a virtual XP machine comes up on demand, and shuts off after the user logs off.

I appreciate an advice in advance.

===================================

EDIT: I'm currently faced with the above work scenario, I know in general I have options but I'm unsure what specifically they are or what would be the best way to proceed. This is why I posted a question to technology site known for answering questions hoping to get some specific guidance.

This is opinion-based question, I don't know why it's a bad thing to ask a pool of people with potentially more experience than yourself how to proceed in a situation that is foreign to you.

Comment: The end of official support for Windows XP doesn't mean it's going to stop working. You won't get any new updates for it but it will continue to run. If you need to use it, and you're OK with the exposure of not getting new updates, then I don't see how virtualizing XP is a solution. Whether virtual or physical the same issue applies so why bother implementing a virtual XP environment. How does that change anything?

Comment: If you do move to Windows 7 then I honestly think that Windows XP Mode is probably the easiest, most straight forward solution. Users will be able to launch the Windows XP program from their Windows 7 Start menu and Desktop shortcuts.

Comment: Your question is way too subjective and isn't a good fit here IMO.  " `What's going to be the easiest way to still support this program moving forward?"` - there's a reason why software lifecycles exist.  Find a way to update the app or get a different one.  Or stay on XP for years for a single legacy app risking updates/fixes/security/etc.  Regardless, there isn't a direct answer that can be given here to tell you what to do in your situation.  If you choose to go the route of building a VDI solution and run into issues, asking those questions here should be OK.

Comment: Maybe see if you get this programming working with App-V? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_App-V

Comment: @joeqwerty While Windows XP won't stop working, it will stop being patched and very quickly become a target for attacks. I'd rather have virtualized XP machines completely locked down and cut off from internet as opposed to letting users continue to use an unsupported OS for all of their programs.

Comment: @joeqwerty We will be moving to Windows 7. While XP Mode may be the most straight forward I'm still researching whether or not it will be the easiest based on the amount of users I'd have to support with a virtual machine installed on each of their machines vs hosting images on server when we already have a virtual server on the network.

Comment: @TheCleaner The application in question is an ERP deeply integrated into our business that's been customized to the point where if we did want to upgrade we'd be paying six figures to do so. Moving to another piece of software won't be quick, easy, or cheap to do which is why I'm looking for a stopgap measure for short term.

Comment: @TheCleaner Additionally, the reason I posted on this page was to get input from people that have possibly been through situation before and to benefit from that wisdom.

Comment: @WinskiTech - "wisedom" in this situation isn't to find a way to keep XP around.  Wisdom is knowing the OS lifecycle, the software's own lifecycle, and planning accordingly.  Obviously you still have time at least on extended support, but the right thing to do here is to start looking at ways internally to make sure you don't have to find stopgaps and bandaids in the future.  And like most of us won't care to admit, stopgaps usually end up being in place forever until ripped out by force.  All said, have you done validation testing of the app on Win 7/8 to see what is or isn't working?

Comment: And besides, the world has known this was coming for SEVERAL YEARS now. Much more than enough time to do something about the application. It's not like this was a surprise. Going forward, one thing you do NOT want to do is to get locked in to a specific OS version.

Comment: We know exactly what the problems are in Win 7/8, it's a combination of hard-coded entries clashing with newer and x64 OSes and all of the customizations that would need to be updated to the latest version that would again, cost six figures. I would love to use another ERP system but if you've been in the manufacturing environment even a little bit you know how hard it is to transition ERP systems.

Comment: @Michael Hampton  If I could get into the history of the situation I would tell you how the decision to move this ERP system was driven completely by not me and the go ahead to put the wheels in motion to move to another ERP system is not up to me. I could also tell you we warned the powers that be this was coming and nothing was done. However, this is all moot right now as it is in the past and unchangeable. The bottom line is I need to find a way to support this legacy, networked application preferably before the Windows XP support cutoff

Comment: I can only say I hope you have copious documentation where you warned the company of what they were getting into by ignoring this issue for years. We've seen several similar questions here recently, and the answer is always the same that you've received: DO NOT DO IT.

Comment: Being in manufacturing myself, they should understand that cGMP and ISO 9001 shouldn't be limited to only the "shop floor".  ERP systems especially should be in compliance.  But again, I digress.  I'm not trying to piss you off, just stating that a stopgap isn't a smart solution here.  You need to convey over and over to them that ALL systems that impact manufacturing need to be kept current, including the ERP system.  If they then choose "too bad, make it work", then document the risk in detail and when an auditor says "WTF?" tell them "yep...hope it is in your report to the C level folks!"

Comment: Take an image of the machine it's running.  You can either use it with virtual box, xen or vmware.  Since you can't use RDP for some reason, try another option like TeamViewer.  It accesses and casts the desktop quite differently than Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

*Being in manufacturing myself, they (your management) should understand that cGMP and ISO 9001 shouldn't be limited to only the "shop floor". ERP systems especially should be in compliance. But again, I digress. I'm not trying to piss you off, just stating that a stopgap isn't a smart solution here. You need to convey over and over to them that ALL systems that impact manufacturing need to be kept current, including the ERP system. If they then choose "too bad, make it work", then document the risk in detail and when an auditor says "WTF?" tell them "yep...hope it is in your report to the C level folks!"*

But, just to show I'm a good sport about your question.

You asked:

> Ideally what I'd like is a server a user can hit and a virtual XP
>   machine comes up on demand, and shuts off after the user logs off.

You also talked about the fact that XP won't get updates eventually and:

> "it will stop being patched and very quickly become a target for
>   attacks. I'd rather have virtualized XP machines completely locked
>   down and cut off from internet as opposed to letting users continue to
>   use an unsupported OS for all of their programs".

You can setup an XP VM on a hypervisor of your choice and "freeze it" using something like [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/standard/).

Or you can still find [Steady State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SteadyState) out on the internet for download and it works well enough.

> SteadyState can revert a computer to a previously stored state every
>   time it reboots, or on administrator's request. When Windows Disk
>   Protection (WDP) component of SteadyState is turned on, changes to the
>   hard disk are redirected to a temporary cache. WDP offers three modes
>   of protection:
>
> - Discard mode: The cache is cleared upon every reboot, thus returning the system to its previous state.
> - Persist mode: Changes saved in the cache remain intact across reboots. An administrator may later opt to commit these changes.
>     Alternatively, at the specified date and time, the cache expires and
>     its contents are cleared.
> - Commit mode: Contents of the cache is written out to disk and become permanent. In addition, new changes to the system are no longer
>     redirected to the cache.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an ideal situation for using VDI. I have in fact managed a pretty large install base of XP VMs on RHEV, accessed using the SPICE protocol, that were optionally stateless. The best part of it was that the users weren't even aware they were using a VM, to them it looked like they were on a local desktop with XP, and all of their regular software.

Comment: +1. Standard VDI problem. Actually Windows has a solution for that out of the box since - well, not exactly server 2003. Upgrade Servers to 2012, use standard VDI. This is a problem LONG solved.

Comment: The built-in solution uses RDP, which according to the t/s, is not an option

Comment: no guarantee that the statement about RDP is correct.

Comment: T/S is not RDP - TS incompatibility is different than redirecting the output (RDP). A lot of software has issues with TS... but works fine in single user mode (xp machine, 1 user per VM) over RDP.

Comment: @TomTom, you might be right there, but it's better to hear from the t/s. The solution I proposed, doesn't use the guest OS to connect you to the desktop, it pretty much gives you kvm-level access to the guest console itself, so you don't get disconnected if the VM reboots or live-migrates. In fact I've run a demo of SPICE with 4 screens attached, all 4 running a DVD movie, and the VM live migrated while the movie was playing - nobody noticed a thing